# Bend the Extrusion of a text

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

As you can see the Extrusion of the text is bent and twisted. Can I achieve that WITHOUT converting it into a mesh? I tried Lattice, Curve, Deform etc...

Thnx,

Cheers

Comment: I don't think there's any other way than CTRL + ALT + C. You just have to set up every bit of text and later make the curves.

Comment: What if you could keep it a curve, just not a text curve, would that be okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the text to a regular Curve object(Alt+C). Add another curve, and make the text that curve's bevel object. Select "Fill Caps" option for solid text. Add Edges Split modifier for sharp edges. You can control (and even animate) extrusion with Bevel Factor Start/End.[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add a subdivision surface modifier and a curve modifier to the text in this exact order. Crank up the subdivision levels to see proper results.

[image]